# Add gnomesu to right-click menu in GNOME/SLES

Tags: linux, gnome, suse

I'm a Windows Server admin who is playing around with SLES 12 SP3, and I'm finding it easy enough to work through most things (Google/RTFM) - but one thing I'm stuck on is the ability to elevate from the right-click menu in GNOME desktop. In Windows, I can elevate just about anything by right clicking it and selecting "Run as Administrator". I'm looking for a "Run as Root" equivalent in GNOME that basically runs gnomesu with the application I've just right clicked as a parameter.

Edit: To further clarify, it would be good if this is universal - ie Right clicking a desktop shortcut, an executable in file manager or a start menu shortcut would all give the same option - but I understand if each one requires its own solution.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to get this functionality?

Comment: Are you talking about executables found through the file manager, or about applications listed in the 'start' menu?

Comment: @grawity - edited. Please see above. :)